# Bootstrap Navbar Collapsing Glitchy When Non-Mobile (fiddle included)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I followed the answer here to get my links to collapse the expanded navbar whenever it's in that dropdown mode:

[Programatically toggle bootstrap 3 navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675336/programatically-toggle-bootstrap-3-navigation-bar)

However when it's NOT in the dropdown mode (desktop), I get a weird "collapse" animation on my regular non-mobile navbar for a split second - it alternates from fading the text of my buttons away between up and down, as if it's trying to collapse the dropped-down navbar that isn't there, so it does it to the content of my main navbar instead.

I have the following code for my menu links:

```
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!--ko foreach: authorizedRoutes -->
            <li>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"></a>
            </li>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
      </div>
```

And this for my collapse icon:

```
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" toggle="offline">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
```

What would be causing this weird glitch?

Here's a jsfiddle where the behavior can be seen - (shrink/expand your browser to see the modes - expanded is where the glitch occurs): http://jsfiddle.net/D2Gsa/11/

Comment: Why don't you compare it to one of the examples on GetBootstrap.com - you are missing the navbar-header class which clears the float so you might be missing more classes.

Answer (score 2):

As for the question "What would be causing this".
You have `data-toggle="collapse"` for the links, which forces them to collapse the whole list container `data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse"`.

You can fix this by removing that `data-toggle="collapse"` for links, that would also cause dropdown to not collapse when clicking them in mobile mode

Also you can overwrite animation transitions for your `.navHeaderCollapse` specifically for non-mobile mode. That way clicking links will collapse whole menu in mobile view but won't do this for wider screens.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navHeaderCollapse.collapsing{
        transition:none;
        -webkit-transition:none;
        -moz-transition:none;
        overflow:visible;
     }
}
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/D2Gsa/13/)