# Bootstrap Navbar Not Folding Back Up Afer Selecting ID Element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap nav bar to navigate to certain elements on the same page. Thus, one of my list elements is

```
` <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

         <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/spi_logo.png" height=30 width=41></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#bio"><span class="fa fa-female"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Bio</a></li>                                

                <!--<li><a id="contact">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="#faq"><span class="fa fa-question"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#quoteform"><span class="fa fa-dollar"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Quote</a></li>
                </ul>           

            </div>
        </div> <!-- end container -->
    </nav> `
```

The navbar collapses nicely on an xs screen. I can click the toggle navigation icon bars, menu drops, and I can select an id element to jump to on the page. However, the menu does not toggle back up after choosing an id to jump to. I assume this is because a new page is not loading, but rather I'm just jumping down the page. So how can I configure the navbar to force it to toggle back up?

Comment: Hi Robert Can You first please post your complete page code if possible . So that we can check some more things

Comment: Do you want navbar to toggle to collapse mode after <li> selection

Comment: I posted the whole navbar code. Yes I want the navbar to fold back up after <li> selection. By fold back up, I assume that means toggle back to collapse. Sorry if I don't use the proper terminology.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programatically toggle bootstrap 3 navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675336/programatically-toggle-bootstrap-3-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675336/programatically-toggle-bootstrap-3-navigation-bar).

Using data attributes will do the trick.

Comment: Your answer inspired me to find this [link](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/) which in turn caused me solve my problem with this `<li><a href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>`

Comment: Its the answer i got you the link for mate. Glad it helped. Could you mark the answer plz ?

Comment: I marked the answer but my rep score is only 9. It has to be 15 to publicly display the up-vote. But yes, I up-vote that!!!